# Memory leaks with strtok

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, strtok

I'm getting some memory leaks in valgrind with strtok and I'm not sure why it's happening.

Possibly lost: 281 bytes in 8 blocks.

Still reachable: 64 bytes in 1 blocks.

I've also tried to call the function with a temporary char pointer instead of the one returned by getenv, but that didn't help.

```
void parsePath(const char * line, vector<string> &pathing) {

    if (line == NULL)
        return;
    char * s = strdup(line);
    if (!s)
         exit(1);

    char * pch;
    pch = strtok(s, ":");
    while (pch!=NULL) {
        string tmp = string(pch);
        pathing.push_back(tmp);
        pch = strtok(NULL, ":");
    }

    free(s);
}
```

I call the function in my main with.

```
const char *pPath;
    pPath = getenv("PATH");
    if (pPath == NULL)
        perror("PATH");

    parsePath(pPath, pathing);
```

Comment: `pPath` and `line` should be `const char *` (the string returned by `getenv` is not modifiable). Instead of `(string)pch` it should be `string(pch)` (call the `string` constructor). And you should ensure that `strdup` returns a non-null pointer.

Comment: Thanks. I made the changes you suggested, but I'm still getting the memory leaks. Is there something I missed?

Comment: this code uses 'vector' from the STL in C++, so it is not C.  The tag needs to be changed from C to C++

Comment: perhaps I missed it, but I do not see the definition of pathing in the main function

Comment: I think the problem was when my program exited from exit(0); If it terminated from return 0, there weren't any memory issues.

Comment: @ooga: For practical purposes, `(string)pch` and `string(pch)` are the same. Both will call `std:string::string(const char*)`, as they're equivalent to `static_cast<std::string>(pch)`

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a false positive from `valgrind`.

In general, memory leaks aren't a big problem in modern C++, but you're clearly using an older style. If you'd use just `std::string` and e.g. Boost.Tokenizer, there wouldn't be anything to leak.